# Can't get source and target uuid's of a connection's endpoints

Tags: jsplumb

I want to reach source and target uuid's of a connection's endpoints in "beforeDrop" event.

I tried;

```
instance.bind("beforeDrop", function (info) {
                alert(info.connection.source.getUuid())
            });
```

But it does not work. How can I reach them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getUuid()](http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/Endpoint.html#method_getUuid) is the Endpoint Class method, so:

```
instance.bind("beforeDrop", function (info) {
    alert(info.connection.endpoints[0].getUuid());
    return true; /* if you need to establish connection */
});
```

But if you need to get endpoints uuids of already established connection the best way will be to use "connectionDragStop" event:

```
instance.bind("connectionDragStop", function(conn, ev) {
    var uuids = conn.getUuids();
});
```